# Angular 2 + jQuery + Materialize - how to Test?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine, materialize

In my angular app I use materialize.css. To login and register users I open modal dialogs. This works in my actual application but not in my unit tests.

The function to open a modal dialog inside the component:

```
openRegisterModal() {
  jQuery('#register_modal').openModal();
}
```

Where the function is called inside the template:

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="!loginService.isLoggedIn()">
    <a id="register" (click)="openRegisterModal()">Register</a>
</li>
```

Now I want to test that the openRegisterModal function gets called after the register link was clicked. But openModal is not a function inside my unit tests. Here the code for my test:

```
it ('should open the register modal if the user is not logged in', () => {
  spyOn(fakeLoginService, 'isLoggedIn').and.returnValue(false);

  fixture.detectChanges();
  clickOnElement('#register', fixture);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.openRegisterModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
})
```

and finally my karma.conf.js where I included jQuery.min.js and materialize.min.js:

```
files: [
  { pattern: './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', watched: false },
  { pattern: './node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js', watched: false },
  { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
]
```

In the beginning I got the error that jQuery is unknown and adding the js file to the config solved the problem. But this does not seem to be the case for materialize.js